# C++ - std::set not declared

Tags: c++, debugging

```
#include <iostream>

 using std::set;
 using std::cout;
 using std::endl;
```

Error reported:

`Josephus_Permutation.cpp:3:13: error: ‘std::set’ has not been declared`

Shouldn't `std::set` be a STL of namespace `std`?

Comment: The vast majority of the `std` library is just handy classes implemented in C++ for you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is in the `std` namespace but you need to include the appropriate header:

```
#include <set>
```

The `<iostream>` header only contains the standard input/output library, which includes `std::cout` and `std::endl`. `std::set`, however, is defined in `<set>`.

Comment: Seems I have asked a stupid question...Thank you.

Comment: @CDT: Humility goes a long way